# Listing and adding JMS Physical Destinations to GlassFish v3.1

Tags: glassfish, jms, administration

After adding a destination(Queue) to Destination Resources from Admin Console at *Resources/JMS Resources/Destination Resources*, no physical destinations are displayed at *server(Admin Server)/JMS Physical Destinations* .Instead, the following error message is displayed below the heading:

**An error has occured**
Unable to list JMS Destinations

Also, on trying to add a new Physical Destination at *server(Admin Server)/JMS Physical Destinations*, of type 'Queue', following error message is displayed:

**An error has occured**
Unable to create JMS Destination

On trying to add a Physical Destination using asadmin in command-line as:

```
asadmin> create-jmsdest -T queue DemoQueue
```

the following error is displayed:

```
remote failure: Unable to create JMS Destination.

Command create-jmsdest failed.
```

Here, GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1-b24 is run on Ubuntu with kernel 2.6.28-11-server.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should create physical destinations manually. All you need to do to set up JMS resources in GlassFish is defining a connection factory and destinations - all under Resources - JMS resources branch in admin interface. When your destinations are used physical destinations will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

confused me to no end first time so I sympathise

For GFv2.1.1 (and I suspect for v3) a physical destination - mq.sys.dmq - is already created and configured and queues are created here.  The messaging server is SunMQ and if it is your intention to use this out-of-the-box then you don't need to create another physical destination.

if you do indeed need to create another physical destination launch [path-to-glassfish]/imq/bin/imqadmin.exe (or ubuntu equiv) and do it there.